# Is a mechanism like Site.createPortalUser available where the Contact already exists?

Tags: force.com-sites, customer-portal

As I understand the [Site.createPortalUser](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_System_Site_createPortalUser.htm) method, it results in a new **Contact** object and **User** object being created.

Is it possible to instead have the **Contact** pre-existing, and to only add the **User** object (and still have the standard new user email process execute) by any means?

The use case is a customer portal where only a small proportion of customers ever choose to register and the registration process is based on the **Contact.Email** field of pre-existing Contacts. (So the registration happy path would be for a single pre-existing Contact to match the email address. Then a means would be needed for the controller to specify that pre-existing Contact when the portal User is created.)

Comment: Just did some more Googling on this and found this post http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Force-com-Sites-Site-com/Contact-creation-in-Site-createPortalUser/td-p/601605 that says a pre-existing Contact (with the same Account) will be automatically matched by email address and re-used. Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went ahead and did some testing to get empirical confirmation of the last comment in the post [Contact creation in Site.createPortalUser](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Force-com-Sites-Site-com/Contact-creation-in-Site-createPortalUser/td-p/601605%20http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Force-com-Sites-Site-com/Contact-creation-in-Site-createPortalUser/td-p/601605) using the CommunitiesSelfRegController. (I started out trying to do this from the developer console but you get told "System.TypeException: That operation is only allowed from within an active site".) Note that the CommunitiesSelfRegController sets the email address for the User but does not set the contactId for the User.

The results confirm the post:

- When you enter an email address for the new user that is not already present in one of the Account's Contacts a new Contact is created
- When you enter an email address for the new user that is present in exactly one of the Account's Contacts the existing Contact is used - **this is the behavior I want**
- When you enter an email address for the new user that is present in more than one of the Account's Contacts a new Contact is created

And some code could be added to CommunitiesSelfRegController to handle the third case differently.