# Registration Problem Communitities

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, community-builder

Calling the **Site.createExternalUser()** method within the ProviderCommunityRegCtl class and we are receiving this error:

> VF_PAGE_MESSAGE|Your request cannot be processed at this time. The
>   site administrator has been alerted.  |USER_DEBUG|[155]|ERROR|User
>   Registration Failed: [There was an error in registering a user in site
>   Provider_Community. The error message is: portal user already exists
>   for contact]

This error only seems to happen if we already have a community user registered to the ACCOUNT even though that community user is tied to a completely different contact.

When we went to the contact detail page for the contact with the ID listed in the snippet above  and manually clicked the enable customer user button the new community user was created successfully.

Comment: Could you please provide an example of a case where you get the error message and a case where you don't?

Comment: Related Question!
http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/18127/is-a-mechanism-like-site-createportaluser-available-where-the-contact-already-ex

Comment: Occur when  a community user registered to the ACCOUNT even though that community user is tied to a completely different contact.       When we went to the contact detail page for the contact with the ID listed in the snippet above and manually clicked the enable customer user button the new community user was created successfully.

Comment: So the contact record exists on an account, but the external user record for the contact does not exist in user objects. Is that an accurate scenario?

Comment: Yes That is the current scenario .

Comment: In that case,you could use a different method to create the community  user.